# Advice on when $f(x,y)=\frac{x^4 + y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^k}$ is continuous/differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have the function $f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^4 + y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^k},  & x \ne0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$

I'm trying to find the the real $k$ such that this function is continuous and differentiable at $(0,0)$. I note that $f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda ^{4-2k}f(x,y)$  implying that for $k>2$ the function blows up when it approaches $(0,0)$. But I can't seem to properly bound the function at that point when $k\leqslant2$ to show continuity or differentiability.

Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^2+y^2$ in a multivariable calculus limit problem near $0$ suggests polar coordinates.

The question of continuity is then equivalent to asking when
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^4(\cos^4 \theta+\sin^4 \theta)}{r^{2k}}=
\lim_{r\to 0}r^{4-2k}(\cos^4 \theta+\sin^4 \theta)
$$
is $0$ independently of choice of $\theta$. this clearly occurs when $2>k$.

As for differentiability,  we must have $2>k$ but we also will need the partials to exist at the origin.

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^4}{h^{2k}}=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{4-2k}=0
$$ 
for $k<2$.

So, by the definition of the derivative, your function is continuous and differentiable as long as 
$$
\lim_{(h,j)\to \vec{0}}\frac{h^4+j^4}{(h^2+j^2)^{k+1/2}}=0
$$
which it does provided
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}r^{3-2k}=0
$$
by the usual polar coordinates business. So you require $k<3/2$. So, your function is also differentiable if $k<3/2$, and just continuous if $3/2\leq k<2$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta$?

Comment: yes sorry thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @JonathanKeogh certainly! I enjoyed the problem

Comment: hi @qbert, I know its been a few weeks but I noticed a (possible?) flaw in your argument for failure of differentiability when $k>0$; you say that computing the partials away from the origin then taking the limit towards $(0,0)$ blows up, hence it can't be differentiable at $(0,0)$. But doesn't there exist functions which are differentiable whose first order partial derivatives are not continuous? That is, if the partials exist at a point and are continuous at that point then this implies differentiability at that point, but the converse is false?

Comment: @JonathanKeogh ok, now I had the time to go through thoroughly, sorry about that. That was a really great catch and I should have been more careful.